# When I used Nginx to proxy tomcat, the concurrency performance dropped dramatically！

Tags: nginx, tomcat, performance-testing, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I used Jmeter to test my Tomcat Server，the TPS is blow（about 30000）：

[the tps of tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stTf5.png)

**However, when I use nginx to proxy tomcat，the performance is too poor(about 7000, and so many error)**

[ths tps of nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbnsb.png)

> Same server and configuration, the only difference is the target url

I don't understand. Why has it changed so much!!

I have optimized the nginx configuration file, as shown below：

```
worker_processes  16;
worker_rlimit_nofile 35535;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  10240;
}



access_log  off;
sendfile        on;
tcp_nopush     on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
gzip  on;
。。。
```